# Check marks in Calendar Days

Tags: image, calendar, click, fullcalendar

I'm currently working on Full Calendar, and I was wondering if someone could help me out. So far I have a calendar that allows the user to select days. Once clicked, particular days change color.

My goal is to add check marks to the days that have been clicked. Does anyone know how this could be achieved?

Attached is the code I have thus far. Thanks a ton  :D
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwLBg.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is set up to use a unicode checkmark but also includes comments for changing to use font-awesome if you like

```js
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  /* Add i tag to all day cells as placeholder for checkmark */
  dayRender: function(date, cell) {
    var check = document.createElement('i');
    check.classList.add('checkbox');
    cell.append(check);
  },
  dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
    var check = $(this).find('i.checkbox'); /* find the i.checkbox */
    /* Simpler than the below but if you need to do other things, if/else better approach */
    check.toggleClass('marked');
    /* if (check.hasClass('marked')) { // font-awesome: fa-check
      check.removeClass("marked"); // font-awesome: fa fa-check
    } else {
      check.addClass("marked"); // font-awesome: fa fa-check
    } */
  },
  events: [{
    start: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
    end: moment().add(1, 'day').format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
    title: 'Event 1'
  }, {
    start: moment().add(1, 'day').format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
    end: moment().add(3, 'day').format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
    title: 'Event 2'
  }, ]
});
```

```css
i.checkbox.marked::before {
  content: '\2713';
  /* unicode check mark */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.9.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.9.0/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id='calendar'>

</div>
```